# In AWS RDS, SQL Agent job fails with "Unable to determine if the owner (Domain\user_name) of job job_name has server access."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory, amazon-rds, sql-agent-job

SQL Agent job is failing for windows authenticated user in AMAZON RDS SQL Server 2016 (15.0.4073.23).

Message The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (Domain\user_name) of job job_name has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'Domain\user_name', error code 0x54b. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).

I am trying to run SSIS package via SQL Agent Job, and have followed this documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-microsoft-sql-server-integration-services-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/

But SQL Agent job itself is failing, probably not the issue with SSIS.

Even simple T-SQL script in SQL agent job is failing, so I am assuming its not related SSIS.
SSIS runs fine in SSMS by manually executing.

Only as sa, Agent Job runs fine. But to run SSIS package, user has to be Windows Authenticated so I have to try use Windows Authentication user. For which I will create sql proxy as mentioned in the amazon documentation.

Since I am new to Active Directory and RDS, I am not sure where to start. But looking at some of similar posts I might need to make some changes in Active Directory but they are not as clear.